# Could anyone clarify this definition?

Tags: functions, intuition

In Michael Spivak's Calculus to explain limits, he uses such an example:

We're given a function $f(x) = \left\{0, \quad \quad \quad \quad x \,\,\, \text{irrational} \\ \quad\quad\quad\quad\frac{1}{q}, \quad \quad \quad x = \frac{p}{q} \,\,\,\text{in lowest terms},\,\, 0<x<1  \right\}$

And we are told that to prove that for any number $a$ with $0<a<1$ the function approaches a at $a$, we consider any number $\epsilon > 0$ and any natural number $n$ large enough, that $\frac{1}{n}\leq \epsilon$.

And here is the part I don't get:

> that $1/n\le\varepsilon$. Notice that the only numbers $x$ for which $|f(x)-0|< \varepsilon$ could be false are: $$\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{3};\frac{2}{3};\frac{1}{4};\frac{3}{4};\frac{1}{5};\frac{2}{5};\frac{3}{5};\frac{4}{5};\ldots;\frac{1}{n},\ldots,\frac{n-1}{n}.$$ (If $a$ is rational, then $a$ might be one of these numbers.) However many of these numbers there may be, there are, at any rate, only finitely many.

What does he mean by **only finitely many**?

Can't I just go on $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 
\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{500}, \frac{1}{5000000000}, \frac{1}{500000000^{5000000000}}$ and so on?

Also then he says that if the distance between $x$ and $a$ is less than the distance between the difference between the closest rational number betewen $0$ and $1$, and $a$, then $x$ is not one of the rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ or in other words:

Set $A$ contains all rational numbers between $0$ and $1$

From all members of $A$, $\frac{p}{q}$ is closest to $a$

$|\frac{p}{q} - a| = \delta$

if $|x - a| < \delta$, then $x$ does not belong in $A$

I don't get it - why doesn't $x$ belong in $A$?It all seems like random assumptions coming out of nowhere, I'm not sure I'm following.Could someone clarify this here?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the first part he is saying that the only numbers for which that function can yield a number that is greater than $\epsilon$ are those whose denominator is $n$ or less, hence the numbers he listed. The number $n$ is fixed at the beginning if that's what's causing confusion. For a specifically chosen $n$ the numbers in the sequence you present eventually become less than $\frac{1}{n}$